# Windows 10 Routed Events list

Tags: xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm new at Windows 10 Universal Windows Apps and XAML and I would like to know were to find a list of RoutedEvents.

I'm trying to animate the Ellipsis button in a commandBar control. I changed the image to an arrow which I need to rotate when it is clicked / tapped.

I edited the control in Blend and I tried to add an animation on the Tap / Tapped / MouseDown routed events. It does'nt work for neither - the events are either not accessible or not recognized.

this is my code

```
<Button x:Name="MoreButton" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" Padding="16,23,16,0" Style="{StaticResource EllipsisButton}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Visible">
                                <FontIcon x:Name="EllipsisIcon" FontSize="16" 
                                          FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" 
                                          Glyph="&#xE768;" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <FontIcon.RenderTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedRotateTransform" Angle="0" />
                                    </FontIcon.RenderTransform>
                                    <FontIcon.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Tap">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRotateTransform" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                                             By="10"        
                                             To="360" 
                                             Duration="0:0:0.5" 
                                             FillBehavior="Stop" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </FontIcon.Triggers>
                                </FontIcon>
                            </Button>
```

Thank you

Comment: `EventTrigger` is not supported in an UWP app, do you want to do this all in xaml code, can't you rotate it in the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can move your animation to one of the visualstates in DisplayModeStates visualstategroup. [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299118.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.routedevent.aspx) for a list of routed events.